# Python - extra keyword(?) and inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

`typing.py` (from Python 3.6.6 as bundled with Anaconda) declares `List` class as follows:

`class List(list, MutableSequence[T], extra=list):`

As far as my understanding goes, it means that `List` class inherits from `list` and `MutableSequence[T]`). What is the meaning of `extra` assignment in the inheritance list?

Comment: There's some more details with regards to class definition arguments in the metaclass documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses - TL;DR extra keyword arguments are passed to the metaclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `typing.py` class `GenericMeta` takes the `extra` keyword argument. The `extra` argument is simply one of the arguments that `GenericMeta` takes for internal bookeeping. The updates happen here in the `__new__` of `GenericMeta`:

```
namespace.update({'__origin__': origin, '__extra__': extra,
                      '_gorg': None if not origin else origin._gorg})
```

From this point on `cls.__extra__` becomes part of `Typing`'s internal API, much like `__getattr__` or `__len__`. From the source code, it looks like `__extra__` is used to help set attributes for the class that it's passed into:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GenericMeta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(self.__extra__, abc.ABCMeta):
        self._abc_registry = self.__extra__._abc_registry
        self._abc_cache = self.__extra__._abc_cache
    elif self.__origin__ is not None:
        self._abc_registry = self.__origin__._abc_registry
        self._abc_cache = self.__origin__._abc_cache
```

This code uses `__extra__` to set `_abc_registry` and `_abc_cache`